# Asp.Net datagrid row selected event

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

In asp.net App I am using datagrid.Is there any event fired when a row is selected?I am not using any select button in grid.

Answer (score 0):

what about : `SelectedIndexChanged`

> "Occurs when a different item is
>   selected in a data listing control
>   between posts to the server"

Comment: That won't fire if there is no select button like he mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedIndexChanged event will fired when you click on Select Command.

You can use a CommandField or a templateField to implement a Select. if you are using a command field enable SelectCommand and assign somthing to Select Text. And if you are using a template filed put a LinkButton on it and Assign Select toCommand property like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnbSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any link button with any command and subscribe to the RowCommand event.